# How to use instance variable to another class into other file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, class

I have file1:

```
class One:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def getData(self):
        username = input("Enter username:")
        pin_code = input("Enter PIN code:")
```

I want to use variables `username` and `pin_code` into other class even in other file (i,e file2)

```
class Two:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def dataFromOtherFile(self):
        print("username and pin code in file1 was",username , pin)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that they *aren't* instance variables right now; they are just local variables to an instance method.

```
class One:
    def getData(self):
        self.username = input("Enter username: ")
        self.pin_code = input("Enter PIN code: ")

class Two:
    def dataFromOtherFile(self, obj):
        print("username and pin code in file1 was", obj.username, obj.pin_code)

one = One()
one.getData()

Two().dataFromOtherFile(one)
```

This is, however, not exactly good program design. Neither class does what a class should, namely encapsulate data and provide methods that act *on* the data. You just have two functions dressed up as methods. For example:

```
def get_data():
    username = input("Enter username: ")
    pin_code = input("Enter PIN code: ")
    return username, pin_code

def data_from_other_file(data):
    print("username and pin code in file1 was", *data)

data_from_other_file(get_data())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. My problem is solved now. And thanks for the suggestion, Actually I'm using PyQt5. As you know in pyqt classes are must be used. so that's I'm using class.